# Update value based on value in previous row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, sql-update

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Persons 
(
     [Date] date null, 
     [PersonId] int null, 
     [Amount] int null, 
     [Value] int null
)
```

And here's some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Persons ([Date], [PersonId], [Amount], [Value])
VALUES
('2020-01-01', 1, 200, NULL),
('2020-01-02', 1, 300, NULL),
('2020-01-03', 1, 400, NULL),
('2020-01-04', 1, 500, NULL),
('2020-01-01', 2, 200, NULL),
('2020-01-02', 2, 300, NULL),
('2020-01-03', 2, 400, NULL),
('2020-01-04', 2, 500, NULL),
('2020-01-01', 3, 0, NULL),
('2020-01-02', 3, 0, NULL),
('2020-01-03', 3, 0, NULL),
('2020-01-04', 3, 0, NULL)
```

My goal: update all of the values in the [Value] column based on values in other columns AND the previous value in [Value] column. Primary key is `date+personId`.

Explained in pseudo code, my logic needs to something like:

```
CASE 
    WHEN [Amount] > 200 AND previous row value IN [Value] = 1, then 2
    WHEN [Amount] > 500 AND previous row value in [Value] = 2, then 3
    WHEN [Date] > '2020-01-01' AND [Amount] = 500 AND previous row value in [Value] = 2, then 4
```

and so on - this captures the general T-SQL code logic..

I only want to update the `[Value]` column where `[Value]` is NULL also.

What is the play here? I've read about using LAG, While LOOP, Recursive CTE, etc., but unsure where to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag` to reference the previous row's value. In your example data `value` would remain `null` though as your `case` logic depends on the previous row which is `null` to start.

However, this is how you might approach it with an updatable CTE

```
with u as (
    select [Date], PersonId,
    case
        when Amount > 200 and Lag(Value) over(partition by PersonId order by [Date]) = 1 then 2
        when Amount > 500 and Lag(Value) over(partition by PersonId order by [Date]) = 2 then 3
        when [Date] > '20200101' and Amount = 500 and Lag(Value) over(partition by PersonId order by [Date])= 2 then 4
    end NewValue
    from Persons
)
update u set Value = NewValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a row number and then self-join. You can extend this idea to Row-2, Row-3, etc.

```
With Qry1 (
    Select  -- Columns from Person table
            , ROWNUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY Date) As Seq
    FROM Persons
)
Select  -- Columns from ThisRow
        -- Columns from PrevRow (values will be null if there is
        -- no previous row for this PersonId and Date)
FROM Qry1 ThisRow
LEFT JOIN Qry1 PrevRow
ON ThisRow.PersonId = PrevRow.PersonId
AND ThisRow.Date = PrevRow.Date
AND ThisRow.Seq - 1 = PrevRow.Seq
```